# Increasing accuracy of solving overdetermined linear system

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, constraint

I am given $48 \times 48$ matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ and I would like to solve system $Ax = b$. I know that $A$ is underdetermined, i.e. there exist many solutions for $x$. Due to some considerations, I also know that certainly, six additional equations must hold (by adding which system of equations becomes unique).

Roughly, I am calculating probabilities where $x$ contains probabilities for each of 48 events.  These six additional equations are because some of the groups of events are independent and equally likely, so I know that each of this group has probability $1/6$.

To implement this in Mathematica I added 6 more rows to $A$, where I put $1$ if the corresponding element in $x$ is a member of some group and $0$ for all that are not members of some group. Then, for $b$ I added 6 numbers, where each of them is $1/6$.

Therefore, I have an overdetermined equation, which I know must have a unique solution. To solve it, I used LeastSquares method. To check whether the solution is accurate enough, I computed the total probability of all events (which by 6 constraint equations should be equal to 1). I found out that computation leads to the value $0.53$, which is unsatisfactory for me. Then, I tried minimizing 1-norm and that leads to the value $0.84$.

My question:

1) What is the most efficient way to solve this problem? I understand that numerical calculations are never perfect, but is there a way to tell Mathematica to consider constraint equations as precise as possible and let numerical errors go into original 48 equations? Having total probability close to $1$ is crucial to me.

2) If I know that my system of overdetermined equations is unique, is there any way of solving it precisely using Mathematica? I.e., what is the way to reduce numerical errors as much as possible?

Vector B: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18BFI9hd8d1MlwxjK9ByRSArhJ-h0rTWT
Matrix A (54x48): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AaKEfz6fbPBbPutJSpSNlGou-ysLrAqr

Comment: Hard to answer without concrete matrices. At 1) Sounds as if you were looking for `LeastSquares`. At 2) `LinearSolve` with exact input will try to compute exact solutions. With floating point input and such tiny matrices, it is quite unlikely that the numerical errors will be be measurable.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the comments, I am not sure I understand the 2). LinearSolve (as I understand) solves only for quadratic matrices. When I add my constraints then the matrix is $54 \times 48$, and LinearSolve does not give answer.

Comment: Ah, I read "unique" for solvable. Anyways, `LeastSquares` should do what you want.

Comment: To second what @HenrikSchumacher noted, it would be very helpful to have a concrete example (full code to generate one would also be fine).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Absolutely. What is the best way to include code or matrices/vectors in my question?

Comment: For code: Just copy the code in `InputForm` to the post, mark it with the mouse and press the "{}" button in the site's editor to highlight it as code. Matrices: Small matrices can be directly copied like code. Larger ones can be provided by a link to an external site (e.g. DropBox, Google Drive etc.). But even better: Try to generate example data _by code_. `RandomReal` is often a great too to build test examples.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I hope this is what you wanted, Matrix A (54x48): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AaKEfz6fbPBbPutJSpSNlGou-ysLrAqr; Vector B: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18BFI9hd8d1MlwxjK9ByRSArhJ-h0rTWT

Comment: Your system is not solvable. The right hand side `b` has a nonvanishing projection onto the orthogonal complement of the range of `A`: `NullSpace[Transpose[A]].b` returns a nonzero vector. So, it is not clear to me at all what you want because your premise "Therefore, I have an overdetermined equation, which I know must have a unique solution." is just false.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Wow, you are absolutely right. Equations come from a physical model which assumes a unique solution, but this is not the case indeed. I am sorry and embarrassed to not check that. But what if the solution was unique?

Comment: If the right hand side lies within the range of `A`,  `LeastSquares` returns the solution with the least $2$-norm. So, if the system is solvable and if there is only one solution then both `LinearSolve` and `LeastSquares` will return the unique solution.

Comment: (I was starting to write substantially the same as @HenrikSchumacher, so I'll just add...) This does not strike me as something one should be embarassed about. A least-squares solution can be useful in its own right even when a system is inconsistent. What you might want to check is whether you got the model slightly wrong, or have a coding error in generating the matrix, etc.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I appreciate your help! I will try to understand where the flaw is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matA = (* from your link *)
vecB = (* from your link *)
xVec = ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, 48}]];
```

Choose six variables such that the corresponding columns in the matrix of constraint-rows has full rank:

```
elimVars = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
If[MatrixRank[matA[[-6 ;;, elimVars]]] < 6, "CHOOSE OTHER ELIMVARS"]
(* Null *)
```

Eliminate the variables and substitute the solution in `matA` and `vecB`

```
elim = Solve[matA[[-6 ;;]].xVec == vecB[[-6 ;;]], xVec[[elimVars]]];

newMat = Transpose[With[{newExpr = matA.(xVec /. First[elim])},
     newb = vecB - newExpr /. Thread[xVec -> 0];
     Coefficient[newExpr, #] & /@ Delete[xVec, Transpose[{elimVars}]]]];

res = xVec /. First[elim] /. Thread[Delete[xVec, Transpose[{elimVars}]] -> 
                                    LeastSquares[newMat, newb]];

matA[[-6 ;;]].res
```

> {0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667}

`res` contains the probabilities, and it is the same however `elimVars` is chosen as long as the submatrix has full rank.

**Alternative:**
The modification below constrains only the sum of the event's probabilities. The result is very similar:

```
xVec = ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[i], {i, 48}]];
elimVar = 1;
elim = Solve[Total[matA[[-6 ;;]].xVec] == 1, xVec[[elimVar]]];
newMat = Transpose[With[{newExpr = matA.(xVec /. First[elim])},
     newb = vecB - newExpr /. Thread[xVec -> 0];
     Coefficient[newExpr, #] & /@ Delete[xVec, elimVar]]];

res = xVec /. First[elim] /. Thread[Delete[xVec, elimVar] -> LeastSquares[newMat, newb]];

matA[[-6 ;;]].res
Total[matA[[-6 ;;]].res]
```

> {0.16671407, 0.16755255, 0.16477448, 0.16694582, 0.1663015, 0.16771158}
>   1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still going through it. Just a fast question - is it possible to solve something similar if groups are given by some equation? For example, if I have two groups and x = {x1, x2}, then 0.4*x1+0.6*x2 = 1/2 and 0.5*x1+0.8*x2 = 1/2. In a sense, groups might overlap and group sums are conditions with coefficients.